# Are sound fronting and raising more common in evolution than their opposites?

Tags: accent, evolution

Fronting: Back -> Central -> Front

Raising: Open -> Open-mid -> Close-mid -> Close

In Great Vowel Shift, it seems that almost every vowel was [replaced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift#Overall_changes) by a further or higher vowel (or their diphtongs). Are fronting and raising more common in evolution of languages than their opposites?

Comment: That's true of the GVS, but not of the Northern Cities VS going on right now.

Comment: @jlawler Your comment made me inquire into temperature's [effect on vowels](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/17180/28113) and my question is now answered completely. If you could write it as an answer I'd accept it.